# Time DataType in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, types

I've created small database under `SQL Server 2008`. Now i wanted to move it to `SQL Server 2005` and it doesn't work since it doesn't have `Time` datatype. What option do I have to store only time in SQL Server 2005. I've written small TimeSheet application which needs to write hours and minutes mostly in format like 05:30:00 (hh:mm:ss) but ss is optional.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to fix C# app to use `DateTime` instead or install SQL Express which isn't really my favorite.

Comment: I'm curious why you just want time. You could store the entire Date and Time and use a Timespan function if you needed the difference between the times. Maybe this isn't what you are looking for but I don't know anything about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was storing like 3 hours 30 minutes. I wasn't needing date since user wasn't supposed to put StartTime and EndTime but just time he spent on something during a day (I've stored date in different field). Then i was able use `SUM()` (well not the real SUM but made on myself in SQL) on Time.

Comment: Hopefully this will teach you why it is a poor practice to develop in a different version of the database than the one on production. You should develop at the lowest version that will be needed in prod.

Comment: So far didn't had that problem with my other application which is 100k lines. This one is simple 2 day code so not a biggie. Didn't expect this minor functionality to be missing in SQL 2005 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 does support the DATETIME datatype, which also includes time. To store only the time, you can use the CONVERT statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '11:22:33')
```

It's not optimal, because the date part is not used, but still takes up storage space. But then again, downgrading a database to a previous version never is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

- None. Out of the box.
- Do it yourself using a CLR based custom type.
- Live with it.

For a timesheet I personally would prefer NOT to have a time field, but to store time as DateTime always - makes it easier in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no `Time` datatype in SQL Server 2005. What I would suggest doing to convert your existing data to your SQL Server 2005 Instance is use something like this:

```
Select CONVERT(DateTime, YourDateTimeColumn, 114) AS [HH:MI:SS:MMM(24H)]
  From YourTable
```

This will give your the current date WITH the time from the existing data. You will have to just strip the date of the time somehow when retrieving the data. This can be done using a Format function in C# (or whatever .NET language you might be using... assuming you are doing that)

Hope that helps.