# Datetime only time is hardcoded by user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

Sir in my database table at some places I am using datetime datatype at that place I need to explicitly set only the particular time so at that time due to datetime variable it takes default value for date and append it to the user defined time can u please suggest any answer.

```
declare @u as datetime
set @u=cast('6:00PM' As DATETIME)
select @u
```

Now I do not want the default date 1900-01-01 18:00:00.000 , here the default date is 1900-01-01
I need output like 18:00:00.000

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: What version of SQL Server it is? If you are using SQL Server 2008, a new datatype [`time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) can be used.

Comment: @shahkalpesh i am using sql  server 2008 but i dont want to use time datatype

Comment: If you only want to record the time; but don't want to use the `time` datatype, and the `datetime`'s default date is also invalid, what do you want the date part of the `datetime` type to be?

Comment: ps. if you want to avoid `time` for backwards compatibility, take a look at the SQL 2005 solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491146/time-datatype-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @u as datetime
set @u=cast('6:00PM' As DATETIME)
select convert(varchar(12), @u, 114)
```

Comment: sir now you check this code when i am trying to assign it to the @s variable again it show that default date                                      declare @u as datetime,@s as datetime
set @u=cast('6:00PM' As DATETIME)
set @s=convert(varchar(12), @u, 114)
print @s

Comment: @Utsav - Yes. That is to be expected. A datetime variable will always have a date part as well as a time part. If you only want the time part you need to use datatype `varchar` or `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with `[TIMEDIFF()][1]`

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('1900:01:01 18:00:00.100','1900:01:01 00:00:00.000');

Result:
18:00:00.100000
```