# Datevalue is getting appended if i try to insert only time value into database

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-2005, datetime-format

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales_main](
[Receipt_no] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[Receipt_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Receipt_Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[User_id] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Total_amt] [float] NOT NULL,
[Discount] [float] NOT NULL,
[To_pay] [float] NOT NULL,
[Paid] [float] NOT NULL,
[Balance] [float] NOT NULL,
[roundoff_amount] [float] NOT NULL,
[CreatedID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedDateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[UpdatedID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UpdatedDateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL)
```

My sql query looks like this

```
sql = "insert into Sales_main(Receipt_no,Receipt_Date,Receipt_Time,User_id,Total_amt,Discount,To_pay,Paid,Balance,roundoff_amount,CreatedID,CreatedDateTime) values(" + bosales.Receipt_no + ",'" + bosales.Receipt_Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "','" + bosales.Receipt_Time.ToString("t") + "','" + bosales.User_id + "'," + bosales.Total_amt + "," + bosales.Discount_amt + "," + bosales.Amt_tobe_paid + "," + bosales.Amt_paid + "," + bosales.Balance + "," + bosales.Roundoff + ",'" + bosales.Createdid + "','" + bosales.Createddate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "')";
```

The output of this query is:

```
43  |27/01/2015 12:00:00 AM |01/01/1900 5:00:00 PM  |admin  |20 |0  |20 |20 |0  |0  |admin  |27/01/2015 12:00:00 AM |NULL   |NULL
```

I want only time value(5:00:00 PM) to be inserted rather than 01/01/1900 5:00:00 PM.

Please help me out.

Comment: post your table schema i.e Create table sql

Comment: I have added schema. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

*Well*, I think you are doing something wrong.

Inserting your time of date value with it's string representation is a bad idea.
You are doing with [`"t"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortTime) like;

```
bosales.Receipt_Time.ToString("t")
```

**Don't do that!** Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

SQL Server has [`time` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) which defines time of a day. MySQL has also has [`TIME` Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html).

And [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) of .NET Framework has [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns time of day for current instance  as a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Then you can insert your value as;

```
bosales.Receipt_Time.TimeOfDay
```

to your `time` typed column.

And, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Note: Looks like you are using SQL Server 2005 and this version doesn't have `time` type. You can read how to convert it to `datetime`: [Time DataType in Sql Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491146/time-datatype-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I am using SQLserver 2005 and it does not have TIME datatype. I tried using TimeOfDay property. But it gave me error while inserting.

Comment: @SuhasKrishna Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491146/time-datatype-in-sql-server-2005 Use `DateTime` but `Convert` it in your sql.

Comment: I tried to convert using  the statement Convert.ToDateTime(bosales.Receipt_Time.TimeOfDay). It's showing error message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'".

Comment: @SuhasKrishna `bosales.Receipt_Time` isn't an already a `DateTime`? You don't need to convert it.

Comment: Yeah. I know. Just tried it because of your suggestion. Help me a way to get out of this

Comment: @SuhasKrishna As I said, you should pass your `DateTime` as a parameter but you need to `CONVERT` to it in your sql query. Take a look at: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/31/sql-server-2005-date-time-only-data-types.aspx