# Syntax Error near to 'WITH'

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression, with-statement

I have a problem , when I execute a query in SQL Server 2014 it's working but when I execute it in SQL Server 2005, I get a "syntax error near 'WITH'"; can someone help me?

Here is my query :

```
WITH TMP AS 
(
    SELECT  
        INWI.Date ,
        Equipe_Cad.MatBCC,
        INWI.Matricule_FS,
        Equipe_Cad.Employe,
        Equipe_Cad.Equipe,Equipe_Cad.Societe,
        Projet.Projet,
        INWI.Quantite,
        RIGHT('0' + INWI.Tps_Net, 9) C 
    FROM
        INWI 
    INNER JOIN 
        Equipe_Cad ON INWI.Matricule_FS = Equipe_Cad .MatFS 
    INNER JOIN 
        Projet ON Projet.EtapeTraitement = 'INWI_PREPAID'  
    WHERE 
        INWI.Date = '02/03/2018'    
)
SELECT  
    Date,
    MatBCC AS Matricule_BCC,
    Matricule_FS,Employe AS Nom,Equipe,Societe,
    Projet,
    CAST(SUM(Quantite)AS int)AS Quantite , 
    SUM(CAST(LEFT(C, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) + 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(C, 4, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) / 60 + 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(C, 7, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) / 3600) AS Temps_Effectif 
FROM 
    TMP 
GROUP BY 
    Date, MatBCC, Matricule_FS, Employe, Equipe, Projet, Societe
```

Thank you

Comment: Apparently SQL Server 2005 doesn't support the short hand of creating a temp table from select, instead switch this to use the top query as subquery and SELECT from it.

Comment: I don't know  how to do this , please can you give me more help

Comment: The **common table expression (CTE)** feature of using a `WITH ....` is a new feature in SQL Server **2008** - you cannot run this code on 2005

Comment: so what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses the original WITH query as a subquery aliased as x then you select from the subquery:

```
SELECT  
    x.Date,
    x.MatBCC AS Matricule_BCC,
    x.Matricule_FS,x.Employe AS Nom,x.Equipe,x.Societe,
    x.Projet,
    CAST(SUM(x.Quantite)AS int)AS Quantite , 
    SUM(CAST(LEFT(x.C, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) + 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(x.C, 4, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) / 60 + 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(x.C, 7, 2) AS DECIMAL(10,8)) / 3600) AS Temps_Effectif 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
        INWI.Date ,
        Equipe_Cad.MatBCC,
        INWI.Matricule_FS,
        Equipe_Cad.Employe,
        Equipe_Cad.Equipe,Equipe_Cad.Societe,
        Projet.Projet,
        INWI.Quantite,
        RIGHT('0' + INWI.Tps_Net, 9) C 
    FROM
        INWI 
    INNER JOIN 
        Equipe_Cad ON INWI.Matricule_FS = Equipe_Cad .MatFS 
    INNER JOIN 
        Projet ON Projet.EtapeTraitement = 'INWI_PREPAID'  
    WHERE 
        INWI.Date = '02/03/2018') AS x    
GROUP BY 
    x.Date, x.MatBCC, x.Matricule_FS, x.Employe, x.Equipe, x.Projet, x.Societe
```

Comment: I have another problem but I can't post it here they told me that I don't have permission , I want to execute this code `DATEDIFF(second, 0, CAST(Temps AS time))/3600. As Temps_Effectif ` but the time is not accepted in sql 2005 and when I put datetime it's giving me a wrong result not the exacte number !! please help me

Comment: There is no Time data type in sql server 2005 as you have found out,
 please read this post,
 it has a few ideas.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491146/time-datatype-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I have tried other types like timestamp and datetime but don't work , I don't know what should I do !

Comment: So you want the difference in seconds? Or do you want to use milliseconds for more precision?

Comment: for example this is the input 1899-12-30 01:31:16.000 and the output is like that 1.660833 the operation is (hours + minutes/60 + seconds /3600) like what we did in the first example

Comment: I found the solution yesssss I did it like that : DATEDIFF(second, 0, CAST(convert(char(15), Temps, 108) AS varchar))/3600. As Temps_Effectif

Comment: Good job. I figured you could do it.