# I want only date in SQL Server(version of SQL server 2005)

Tags: c#, sql

Folks, I have a question regarding the Date in SQL server 2005 version(Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00). I'm trying to write the query to get the date but in SQL 2005 version. The DataType Date doesn't work? Only the option to use DateTime DataType. The problem with the data type DateTime is it takes the default time 00:00:00.000. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: The date is traditionally considered equal to the time at midnight when the day starts.

Comment: What is the format that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: You're over *6* versions behind the current version. It's not been supported, even in extended support, since 2016. It's beyond time to upgrade.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever While you're not wrong, not everyone has the option to upgrade. Some people are bound by the constraints set by their employers, no matter how frustrating / arbitrary they may be

Comment: The below like looks like the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491146/time-datatype-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Display date using short date string.

Console.WriteLine(Effective.ToString("d"));

// OUTPUT will be     1/2/2016

The above code worked for me. If you replace "d" with "t" you'll get only time.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 111);
```

Instead of 111 you can also use values 101, 102, 103 etc.,